# How I use distributed lock on Apache Ignite?

Tags: locking, ignite

case1：According to the official documentation I tried to use the “Distributed Locks” with transactional mode. but it will occur the below when I restart or scale the cluster.so than the new node cannot start
^-- Transactions in deadlock.
^-- Long running transactions (ignore if this is the case).
^-- Unreleased explicit locks，

case2：the ignite.reentrantLock API found in the code ,I try to use it simply,and not error issue found.but this API can not found in official documentation. Is it officially recommended to use it in a production environment?

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1**

> I tried to use the “Distributed Locks” with transactional mode

As the [doc](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/distributed-locks) says, "Explicit locks are not transactional and cannot not be used from within transactions". Don't use both at the same time.

**Case 2**

Yes, `org.apache.ignite.Ignite#reentrantLock` is an official public API:
https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/Ignite.html#reentrantLock-java.lang.String-boolean-boolean-boolean-

Comment: CASE2
Now I found the following problem. When I start a cluster of four nodes, two nodes can acquire the lock. But the other two nodes can't acquire the lock even when the lock is not occupied(I also print the value of lock.isLocked(). it is false). The usage method is ignite.reentrantLock('xxx',true,true,true)  How do I need to use it?